# iOS7 tab switcher interaction - is there a name for this?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, ios

This is the original switcher, I think you've all [seen how it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm2Sd0VUU0o).

[image]

I'd like to use (or implement) a widget with interaction similar to this app switcher (especially the scrolling), but in my app it would show user reviews instead of apps, and user avatars instead of app icons. Is there any name for this type of component, so that I could ask Google for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look for **PageViewController**, **Cover Flow**, **Carousel**, etc.  There is no built in component for doing this that I'm aware of.

You could roll your own, with enough time and effort, or maybe look into one of these libraries:

- [SCSafariPageController](http://cocoapods.org/pods/SCSafariPageController) (component for pages like tabs in safari)
- [iCarousel for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel) (a Objective-C component with various types of carousels like cover flow, etc)
- [Jazz Hands](https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands) (a keyframe-based animation framework for UIKit, where it is possible to control the animation via scrolling)

Comment: The developer behind iCarousel also maintains [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView), which is similar to iCarousel, but foregoes all of the animation options to feel more like a standard paged UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

## multitasking UI

Multitasking lets people switch quickly among recently used apps. In iOS 9 (on eligible iPad models) people can use the multitasking UI view more than one app onscreen.

source: [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Multitasking.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Multitasking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH38-SW1)

Comment: I was asking about the interaction, not about the task the user accomplishes through it. iOS design changes and the interaction is also different. "Multitasking UI" is imho as good as "app switcher", and does not answer my question.